# Return function after kicking off background process

Tags: asynchronous-programming, golang

I have a process in golang that I want to kickoff through a RPC call but then have the function return early whilst the process continues in the background.  Specifically it’s just a basic db transfer from one db instance to another.

At the moment they way its working is I have my function kickoff a go routine and return early, then have some mechanism to check the status of the go routine (whether in progress, complete or error state).
Im wondering if this is a good approach for this as it seems like it could be simplified somewhat or made more resilient?
Error case generally would initiate retry from the last batch but Im worried that Im building complexity in this that will be difficult to roll back.  Should I be instead looking at some queue based system or maybe a streaming RPC?  Keep in the mind the app is already consuming and producing to multiple topics so adding another worker is going to potentially bloat the service. In most cases the data being transfered shouldnt take longer than a few minutes, but there are edge cases where it may be otherwise.
Is there a specific pattern I can look at implementing here ?

Comment: Is your current approach working well, reliable, and can be easily understood? If the answer is "yes", what's your actual  problem?

Answer (score 2):

Define a manifest constant `TIME_LIMIT=300` seconds
which describes the duration within which you believe
most successful copies will complete.

> some mechanism to check the status of the go routine (whether in progress, complete or error state)

Write a pair of timestamps:

- requested
- completed

This implies several things.

If `completed > requested`, we are in a Success condition.
And it would be perfectly fine to make a new copying request,
since everything is normal.

If not, we can look at `elapsed = now() - requested`.
If `elapsed < TIME_LIMIT`, we are in a Pending (or Progress) condition.
Else the operation is taking "too long",
for example due to a server rebooting in the middle of it,
and we might want to retry.

---

Recording timestamps is very easy.

For example, it could be as simple as
`/usr/bin/touch requested.txt`,
and then `stat()` reports `mtime` (modified time).